# Unshown compile error in Altium Designer 13.1

Tags: schematics, altium

I have a schematic sheet in Altium Designer 13.1 and I made an unconnected label (in the red rectangle) on purpose.

[image]

My problem is: when I compile this sheet, there is no error shown in the `Compile Errors` tab but I definitely have one, a "Floating Net Label" type.

[image]

Do I miss some settings here and that's why I can't see the error(s)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution found: to see errors in the `Compile Errors` tab the following steps should be done:

1. Compile project
2. Open   `View-->Workspace Panels-->System-->Messages` tab
3. Here you can see all warnings and errors, double clicking on an item will show the speific error in the `Compile Errors` tab

[image]

Comment: Just a comment. You can define what is an error and what is a warning or what should not be displayed at all. You can find this in Project Properties -> Connection Matrix and another tab next to it (don't remember the name right now).

Comment: I thought that the results of the compilation will be shown in the `Compile Errors` tab, but I was wrong and the results are displayed in the `Messages` tab, which was not visible for me.